# Memory allotment of for loop in python

Tags: python, memory-management, memory-leaks, profiler

I am confused with memory usage of python for a function.
I am running a function where a pandas dataframe is being returned (1161 X 240) and arguments are (bamfile, pandas.Dataframe(1161 X 50)).

Now I will give the memory usage by profiler:

```
Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
================================================
   120  983.363 MiB    0.000 MiB   @profile
   121                             def overlapping_peaks_distribution(bam_peak1, overlap_df):
   122                                 '''
   123                                 Returns dataframe for tag count distribution for overlapping peaks within 500bp (+,-) from summit.
   124                                 This function also considers the gene transcrition direction.
   125                                 :param bam_peak1:
   126                                 :param overlap_df:
   127                                 :return:
   128                                 '''
   129  983.363 MiB    0.000 MiB       import pandas as pd
   130  983.363 MiB    0.000 MiB       import sys
   131  983.363 MiB    0.000 MiB       peak_distribution_sample = pd.DataFrame()
   132  983.363 MiB    0.000 MiB       print 'Process: Feature extraction from BAM started'
   133 1783.645 MiB  800.281 MiB       for ind, row in overlap_df.iterrows():
   134 1782.582 MiB   -1.062 MiB           sys.stdout.write("\rFeature extraction for peak:%d" % ind)
   135 1782.582 MiB    0.000 MiB           sys.stdout.flush()
   136 1782.582 MiB    0.000 MiB           chr = str(row['chr'])
   137 1782.582 MiB    0.000 MiB           orientation = row['Next transcript strand']
   138 1782.582 MiB    0.000 MiB           middle = row['start'] + row['summit']
   139 1782.582 MiB    0.000 MiB           start = middle - 3000
   140 1782.582 MiB    0.000 MiB           stop = start + 50
   141 1782.582 MiB    0.000 MiB           list_sample1 = []
   142                                     #total_tags = int(bam_peak1.mapped) will get total no of mapped reads
   143                             
   144 1782.586 MiB    0.004 MiB           for i in range(0, 120):
   145 1782.586 MiB    0.000 MiB               tags1 = bam_peak1.count(chr, start, stop)
   146 1782.586 MiB    0.000 MiB               start = stop
   147 1782.586 MiB    0.000 MiB               stop = start + 50  # divide peaks into length of 25 bp
   148 1782.586 MiB    0.000 MiB               list_sample1.append(tags1)
   149 1782.586 MiB    0.000 MiB           if orientation > 0:    # Direction gene transcription
   150                                         #print 'Towards 5 prime'
   151 1780.883 MiB   -1.703 MiB               peak_distribution_sample = peak_distribution_sample.append(pd.Series(list_sample1), ignore_index=True)
   152                                     else:
   153                                         #print 'Towards 3 prime'
   154 1783.645 MiB    2.762 MiB               peak_distribution_sample = peak_distribution_sample.append(pd.Series(list_sample1[::-1]), ignore_index=True)
   155                                 #print peak_distribution_sample
   156 1783.645 MiB    0.000 MiB       return peak_distribution_sample
```

I dont understand why in **line 133** it increments 800MB(insane). This is eating up all the space in my memory. I don't know is this some fault from me?

I used object graph to look for the memory leaks.
Number of object before the function started:

```
(Pdb) objgraph.show_most_common_types()
function                   15293
tuple                      4115
dict                       3086
cell                       2670
list                       2107
weakref                    1834
wrapper_descriptor         1760
builtin_function_or_method 1655
getset_descriptor          1235
type                       1232
```

Number of objects after function finished.

```
(Pdb) import objgraph
(Pdb) objgraph.show_growth()
function                      16360     +1067
dict                           3546      +460
list                           2459      +354
tuple                          4414      +306
getset_descriptor              1508      +273
builtin_function_or_method     1895      +240
weakref                        2049      +215
module                          593      +123
wrapper_descriptor             1877      +117
type                           1341      +109
```

We can see a significant increase in objects.
I also produced some graph.
[image]

I believe the **red font box** suppose to be freed but they are not.

Comment: It's quite possible that `overlap_df.iterrows()` loads that entirely in memory before beginning the first iteration.

Comment: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/7683

Comment: That could be an issue but how to free that memory.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it isn't showing total size of `overlap_df`?

There is the analogous thing here:

> 144 1782.586 MiB    0.004 MiB           for i in range(0, 120):

Profiler shows total size of list of 120 ints as 400 KB.

Comment: That mean overlap_df is of 800MB in size. This is not possible because on physical memory it take space of 8MB. I read that with every iteration it allocate memory but does not release it. In the end function finish with printing out_of_memory(). I also tried **gc.collect()** but it does not effect. nested loops make it worse.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the memory leak. It was because of a third party module **(pysam)** which had a memory leak.